# Emails In Inbox Originating From The Same Address (Yahoo! Spam)

Tags: email, spam-prevention

I have a client who gets spam emails addressed as her email address. For example:

> From: emailaddress@yahoo.com
>
> To: emailaddress@yahoo.com
>
> Subject: Pills, etc.

How do I deal with this junk? I changed her password to a more robust one but that didn’t stop the spam from coming in still.

Comment: You did not mention what she is using? or the OS, or the method of mail recovery (web based, pop etc)  .  When the from address was fraud, we would look in the e-mail "header" or the source data or whatever it is called .In there you can usually find the "real" address and/or origins.

Comment: the bigger problem is yahoo putting an ISP's email server in its banned list then you email yourself and your own email to yourself goes in the spam folder!  At least in this case yahoo is getting it right!!

Answer (score 0):

The spammer got her address somehow and is forging the sender address. Yahoo apparently does not do well in sending these to the spam folder. i suggest that she changes email address, or even provider that is more secure and more spam-free.

Answer (score 0):

You say this:

> I have a client who gets spam emails addressed as her email address.

And then say this.

> How do I deal with this junk? I changed her password to a more robust
>   one but that didn’t stop the spam from coming in still.

The SPAM is forged as being from her address and it’s painfully simple for anyone in the world to pretend the `from` address in an e-mail is something that it is not. So changing her password won’t stop this issue. In fact if somehow hackers got her e-mail address, the least they would do is use it to send SPAM to her; but that is a whole other discussion.

That said the best thing she can do as a user is to apply some kind of junk mail filtering to her mailbox. You don’t state what OS she’s on or what e-mail clients she is using, but Gmail, Yahoo and even Mac OS X mail have built in junk filtering capabilities.

Now if the concern is whether SPAMmers will e-mail others pretending to be her? You can’t control that. The most basic SPAM filters in the world should be able to detect that level of forgery and anyone nowadays using e-mail should have SPAM filtering of some kind in place.